# Sitecore permissions issue

Tags: asp.net, iis, sitecore

I have a sitecore site running on .NET 4.0 and IIS 7.5 on Windows 7 machine.

While setting up sitecore, I had installed only the sitecore client and then set up IIS7. I think some permissions have got messed up because of that. 
Whenever I try to change a code file in my website in Visual Studio, it gives me a message that I don't have any permissions to modify the files. I can overwrite the existing one, however, this is not normal.

Also, I have ApplicationPoolIdentity set as my Identity for my Application Pool. Whenever I try to go to sitecore desktop it doesn't work, however I can go to content editor upon login. Even after logging in, if I try to go to sitecore desktop mode like /sitecore/shell/default.aspx, the page never loads and the progress wheel just keeps spinning. 
It happens in FF, Chrome and IE so it can't be a browser issue.

I checked the permissions of various folder and they all look fine. System, Administrator and Local computer user have full control on the website folder and the files and folders underneath it.

It would be great if someone can help in trying to figure out the right configuration and settings for my website folder.

Comment: Are you running VS as 'administrator?'

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as per the best practice of installing Sitecore, we should set the identity as NetworkService. 
So please do 2 things:

1. Change the Identity in Application Pool as Network Service
2. Make sure that Website and all its descendants + the Data Folder and all its descendants have Read & Write access for Network Service.

Mostly this should work.

Regards,

Varun Shringarpure

Comment: In IIS 7.5, it is suggested to use ApplicationPoolIdentity rather than using NetworkService.

Comment: Generally, in any sitecore installations, it is recommended to use Network Service as App pool Identity. Correct me if i am wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Does `IUSR` have "Read" permissions on the `\Website` folder and on all descendants?

Additionally, you may want to look at the Sitecore logs under the `\Data\logs` folder.  You may be having a database connectivity issue that may show up there.

Comment: This seems like general good advice rather than an answer. In the future you should consider posting such advice as a comment as this does not directly attempt to answer OP's question but rather asks for clarification or privides critique.

Comment: Yes, IUSR has full control on the Website and everything underneath it.